# Date getting modified after object is saved in database(Java,Spring)

Tags: java, spring

So i am making a new-content by creating a object and calling create method and setting the create date when i stored the object it modifies the date to current date. Please help to save the old date in database. below is the line from one of controller

```
Content newContent = this.contentService.create(this.contentUtils.getEditedContentFromOldContent(oldContent,contentDto));
```

Paramter method.....

```
public Content getEditedContentFromOldContent(Content oldContent, ContentDto contentDto) throws APIException {
    Content content = this.beanMapper.map(contentDto, Content.class);
    content.setId(null);
    content.setCreateDate(oldContent.getCreateDate());
    content.setLastModifiedDate(new Date());
    content.setUpdatedBy(oldContent.getUpdatedBy());
    content.setUser(oldContent.getUser());
    ContentCategory contentCategory = this.contentCategoryService.get(contentDto.getCategoryId());
    if (null == contentCategory) {
        throw new APIException("Invalid category Id :: " + contentDto.getCategoryId());
    }
    content.setContentCategory(contentCategory);
    return content;
}
```

create method

```
public Content create(Content content) throws ServiceException {
    if (contentAccessUtil.getAccess(content, "UPLOAD_CONTENT")) {
        return contentRepository.save(content);
    } else {
        throw new ServiceException("Access Denied");
    }
}
```

Pojo class create date

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "create_date", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Date createDate;
```

I have already debugged the value of oldcontent.getcreate date which is 02-05-2015 when i set this value the database still store the current date and i want to store the previous date. It would be great if someone can help me regarding this.In database the type of create-date is date-time.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have on a DB level set for that column something like that default value is NOW() or do you have some trigger in db?

Comment: @nick79 no ..there is no default value .